# How to put comma, if a variable exist without using if statement.

Tags: php, mysql

I have like 10 columns in mysql table.

```
tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6, tag7, tag8, tag9, tag10
```

Now, If tag1 always have a value. But other tag do not always have a value

If, tag2 have a value, then only tag 3 or higher tags will have a chance of having a value. so on...

If `tag6` have a value, then `tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5` 100% have a value, but cannot say about `tag7,tag8,tag9,tag10`

Got it? If no, ask me in comment section.

Now, I echo those results like this:

```
'.$result[$x]["tag1"].' '.$result[$x]["tag2"].' '.$result[$x]["tag3"].' '.$result[$x]["tag4"].''.$result[$x]["tag5"].''.$result[$x]["tag6"].''.$result[$x]["tag7"].''.$result[$x]["tag8"].''.$result[$x]["tag9"].''.$result[$x]["tag10"].'
```

Result will be something like this:

```
John Emma Josh Tripp Ravina Ron Chandler Joey
```

Now, I can put comma using If statements, but i need to use a lot of if statements, which i do not want. Like 9-10 If statements.

Any other way than that?

Comment: This looks like it should be `one-to-many` instead of a `bucket` methodology.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(',', tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6, tag7, tag8, tag9, tag10) as tags
```

Note:  This assumes that the missing values are `NULL`.  If they are empty strings, then the construct is a bit more complicated:

```
select concat_ws(',', tag1, nullif(tag2, ''), . . . ) as tags
```

Your data model is highly suspicious.  Instead of storing multiple tags in a columns in a single row, you should have separate table with one row per tag.  Then you could use `group_concat()` to get the output you want.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: tag1 in

Comment: @RahulSharma . . . I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean.  Do you know how to construct a SQL query?  Do you know what your columns are called?

Comment: SELECT id, name, concat_ws(',', tag1, nullif(tag2, ''), nullif(tag3, '')) FROM TABLE

Comment: echo '  '.$result[$x]['GROUP_CONCAT(tag1)'].' '.$result[$x]['GROUP_CONCAT(tag2)'].'  ';

Comment: Error: Notice: Undefined index: GROUP_CONCAT(tag1)

Comment: @RahulSharma . . . Nothing in my answer has `group_concat()`.  I have no idea where that comes from.  If you want to refer to the column, give it a name and use the name.  I just added the name `tags` for the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), like this:

```
echo implode(", ", $result[$x]);
```

Comment: Yes, you use it like anything else. My code above uses it in an echo. Alternatively if you want it in the middle of a string use concat, `echo "my string " . implode(", " $result[$x]) . " end of my string.";`

Comment: I used ' . `implode(", " $result[$x]["tag2"]) . '`

And got this error `
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' `

Comment: You missed the comma between the two arguments. It's `implode(", ", $result[$x])` Don't specify the individual tags, you just pass in the array of all tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to add comma between tags and use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) without callback to get array with not-empty value:

```
echo implode(', ', array_filter($result[$x]));
```

> **array_filter**: If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.